# Websocket API inconsistent function duration

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I have a websocket API using AWS APIGW. Only problem is, it is very inconsistent with whether or not it times out. Reading through the logs, I am not seeing any errors, only that the same function with same inputs takes significantly more time to run then it did 2 seconds before. Here is my code

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    connectionId=connectionId

    body = json.loads(event['body'])
    message = body['message']
    
    apigatewaymanagementapi = boto3.client('apigatewaymanagementapi', endpoint_url = endpoint)
    
    apigatewaymanagementapi.post_to_connection(Data=message, ConnectionId=connectionId)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200
    }
```

Here are my logs:

```
2020-12-18T02:33:47.178-05:00   {"action": "onMessage", "message": "hello"}
2020-12-18T02:33:47.765-05:00   END RequestId: 5ce356a0-dc4a-40da-956a-ff754acf70c2
2020-12-18T02:33:47.765-05:00   REPORT RequestId: 5ce356a0-dc4a-40da-956a-ff754acf70c2  Duration: 628.00 ms Billed Duration: 629 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 26 MB  
2020-12-18T02:33:49.232-05:00   START RequestId: 608a007b-50c1-4052-b70e-2843a69c7d72 Version: $LATEST
2020-12-18T02:33:49.237-05:00   {"action": "onMessage", "message": "hello"}
2020-12-18T02:33:52.238-05:00   END RequestId: 608a007b-50c1-4052-b70e-2843a69c7d72
2020-12-18T02:33:52.238-05:00   REPORT RequestId: 608a007b-50c1-4052-b70e-2843a69c7d72  Duration: 3003.36 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 27 MB  
2020-12-18T02:33:52.238-05:00   2020-12-18T19:33:52.238Z 608a007b-50c1-4052-b70e-2843a69c7d72 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

**You can see the duration of the first event is significantly shorter then the duration of the second event, even though they are identical**

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to prevent it?

Comment: First off, you could change your Lambdas timeout (3s at the moment) to something higher (max. 900s). If you want to know why your Lambda times out, you have to dig deeper. Since you did not post all your code, there might something wrong with your Lambda that causes long cold starts (cold start = lambda is started for the first time and initialises). There is also a sync HTTP call in your code (`post_to_connection`), which might just take a while to complete. Uncomment and test. You should also have a look at X-Ray. That will tell you how long the HTTP call takes.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking at the APIgw timeout not lambda

Comment: So that answered your question? If so, please write an answer to your question and accept it. This is allowed and helps others to find out how you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** All I had to do was increase the timeout on the lambda function!